What's the tight upper bound for the $L^\infty$ norm of a truncated Fourier series?
Consider the truncated Fourier series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx),
$$
where $a_n,b_n \in [-1,1]$. What's the tight upper bound for $\|f(x)\|_\infty$?
A naive answer is
$$
|f(x)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|+|b_n| = 2N.
$$
A better answer using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is
$$
|f(x)| \leq \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n^2+b_n^2)^{1/2}[\cos^2(nx)+\sin^2(nx)]^{1/2} = 2^{1/2} N.
$$
However, this bound may not be tight. I wrote a code to find the maximum for many random numbers $a_n,b_n$ and there seems to be a lower upper bound.
